# Eigen3: coefficient-wise multiplication in place

Tags: optimization, eigen, eigen3

How can you perform a element-wise multiplication in place using Eigen3?

Does

```
a = a.cwiseProduct(b);
```

run in place? Or is

```
a.array() *= b.array();
```

the better solution in terms of style and performance?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Both expressions should generate the same code (with a reasonably optimizing compiler), so it is more a question of taste.

If you are doing mostly element-wise operations with `a` and `b` you should declare them as `Eigen::Array` (instead of `Eigen::Matrix`) and just write `a*=b;`. If you need to access `a` or `b` in a matrix-fashion later, you can still use `a.matrix()`.